# SSRS inserting blank page

Tags: reporting-services, subreport, page-break

I have a main report calling three subreports. The subreports are being grouped together by the CourseID field. Page 1 shows course 1 for the first two reports. The third subpreport is for comments. If course 1 has comments, they will show up on page 2. If there were no comments, page 2 will be first two subreports for course 2.
The problem is that a blank page is showing up on page 2 when there are no comments for the course.
I have a tried grouping the three subreports in two different ways, as shown in the attached image. The attempt 1 is the one displaying the issue I just described. Attempt 2 does not insert a blank page, but it does not page break on the comments subreport either. It adds the comments to the bottom of the 2nd report.
I removed the page break between each group instance in the group properties and tablix properties of the 3rd report because it was not making a difference whether or not I had them anyway.
I also have ConsumeWhitespaceContainer enabled on the main report properties. It adds several more empty pages if set to false.
The width margins on all four reports are calculated with the tablix width figured in. The subreport widths in the main report are wider than the actual subreport width as well. [subreport groupings in the main report](https://i.stack.imgur.com/clWfN.jpg)

Is there a setting I am missing in the design view?

Comment: I can't test right now but another option would be to create a subreport that produces the entire output for a single Course (so it would contain your 3 current subreports). Then just call that for each course. That way you can easily control when the page breaks occur.

Comment: I have tried this previously. The first two subreports are using the same stored procedure as the dataset. They just each have a filter to show only certain records. I tried combining them into one report with two tablixes, but was not able to group on the course field. So it gave all records for one tablix and then the other.

Comment: I think you misunderstood. I meant create a report that uses your existing subreports but takes a parameter that means it only produces for a single CourseID. Then your 'master' report would just call this report in a tablix or list for each CourseID.